# List View displaying weird texts (Android Studio)

Tags: android, listview

It was marked as a duplicate by someone but it's quite different since its "duplicate" deals with URL when clicking.

So what I would want is when I launch the app I'm trying to make is it would generate random article headlines from a list of headlines I made. However, instead of doing that, it displays some random stuff containing a directory I think of my activity. I was able to do it in another app I made, got the same logic and now it won't work for this specific app.

Here's the portion of my code where I try to generate a random headline:

```
    private void randomArticle() {
            String mArticleRandom[] = {"Anton, tuli na!", "Karlo, nanganak na!", "La Salle Wins Shell ECO", "Andreev, sinagot na ni Janella!", "Norman, ang bagong Hashtag!"};
            //String mStatusRandom[] = {"So puhrung like", "Patayin ko kayong lahat!", "Pagod na ako maging single :(", "I like Andreev", "Hina ng soul ko"};

            for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
                Random post = new Random();
                int article = post.nextInt(5);
                //int message = post.nextInt(5);
                mArticleList.add(new Article(mArticleRandom[article]));
            }
            return;
        }



   mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Article>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mArticleList);

    ListView lstArticles = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_article);
    lstArticles.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    lstArticles.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


       Intent launchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ArticleContentActivity.class);


                Article article = mArticleList.get(position);
                // String targetAuthorStr = article.getAuthor();
                startActivity(launchIntent);
                return;
            }
        }
);
```

And here is what it displays:

[image]

Comment: try putting some random value for article and then check your output..

Comment: Can you also post your Adapter you used for your ListView?

Comment: Please show the lines of code where you add the text to the lists TextView.

Comment: What does your Article class hold? Only a String variable?

Comment: Updated my post. Included the adapter part.

Comment: The fact that the duplicate deals with URLs doesn't matter at all. The main point is that you need to override the `toString()` method in your `Article` class to return what you want displayed in the `ListView`. Read the very first sentence in the accepted answer on the linked duplicate.